# vb.net .Find exact match

Tags: vb.net

Hello I am trying to find the exact match of a string in excel and not a part of it the cell has to equal the exact string and not just part of it here is what I got.

```
Private Sub txtSMaterial_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSMaterial.Leave
    strEX = txtSMaterial.Text.ToString()
   Found = oSheetExtrusions.Range("A6:A5000").Find(What:=strEX, _
                                                        LookIn:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, _
                                                        LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, _
                                                        SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, _
                                                        SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext)

    If Found Is Nothing Then
        txtSLength.Text = "N/A"
        Exit Sub
    Else

    End If

    txtSLength.Text = strExLength

End Sub
```

Comment: fixing the code of your original question invalidates the question for anyone in the future. The accepted answer should be enough information to answer the question if not ask for clarification. If you must put the answer in your question please leave the original question intact while adding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the parameter to look at xlWhole.  See below search function

```
Dim aCell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim oSht As Worksheet
Dim searchString As String
//Set to your sheet name
Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")
//Set to your search parameter
searchString = "101010101"
Set aCell = oSht.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Find(What:=searchString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole,       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Comment: Do you add a reference to Excel?  Any specific error message?  Did it compile okay?

Comment: Yes of course this that is not my problem my code works but it does not grab the exact match Example say I have 100 rows in excel and I search for 3500 it will grab the first cell that has 350040 or 350060 and just the searched string of 3500 I dont want it to find parts of another cell I want the Whole cell to equal what was searched

Comment: See Edit.  Need to specify to LookAt:=xlWhole  And of course there may be a few extra parameters you could remove/change to fit your specific need.

Comment: this have worked for me.Found = oSheetExtrusions.Range("A6:A5000").Find(What:=strEX, _
                                                            LookIn:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, _
                                                            LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, _
                                                            SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, _
                                                            SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext)